# scale changing number to a range using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a changing number 0-100,

now I need to convert it to the range 20-60,

so when I have 0, it will be 20, and so on...

How can I do?

Comment: Can you include `javascript` tried at Question ? , create stacksnippets to demonstrate ?

Comment: Simply `x * 0.4 + 20`. And this is how I got `0.4`: `(60 - 20)/(100-0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scale factor is `(newMax - newMin) / (prevMax - prevMin)`. You also need to move along the number line by `newMin - prevMin`

```
function generateScaleFunction(prevMin, prevMax, newMin, newMax) {
    var offset = newMin - prevMin,
        scale = (newMax - newMin) / (prevMax - prevMin);
    return function (x) {
        return offset + scale * x;
    };
};
```

Usage

```
var fn = generateScaleFunction(0, 100, 20, 60);
fn(  0); // 20
fn( 25); // 30
fn( 50); // 40
fn( 75); // 50
fn(100); // 60

// please note you are not guaranteed an int
fn(1); // 20.4
```

Comment: Thank you for your timely and helpful solution mate! :)